# ArrayList containing references to TreeNodes, what is the space complexity?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, space-complexity

```
   TreeNode root = new TreeNode(5);
    ArrayList<TreeNode> arr = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        arr.add(root);
    }
```

In the above code, a single `TreeNode` object is added into the `ArrayList<TreeNode> arr` for n times. I think that `arr` should have a space complexity of `O(1)` because it is saving references to single memory block on heap. I am discussing this with my friends and they have different opinion that it might have `O(n)` complexity.  What do you guys think?

Comment: The answer would depend on what n is.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving references, but they are still n references. I think you're actually looking for a memory overhead for storing n objects in an `ArrayList`. The memory used will probably be dominated by the actual objects, but there is still an array with length n backing that `ArrayList` holding the references.

Comment: What if my TreeNode object has very huge memory (say 500KB) allocated to it, and each reference (here Object data structure) wont take any where near to 500KB, so in these situations I should say that the space complexity will be O(1)? Because references memory is very less compared to the actual object's memory.

Comment: Compared to the actual memory used by the objects, the memory used by references is way too small to take into account. But you'll have to consider it as O(n) because at the end of the day, it's still an array and if the n is large enough, it will count. Think about an object put in a list about 10k times. There is only 1 object and 10k references. Do you see it now? The O(n) is there and at this point the references will probably use more memory than the actual object. Note: the 10k is an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList still needs to store the reference n times, making it O(n).

ArrayList is backed by an `Object[]`, if you look at the source code

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacity(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

Whenever an element is added it added to the backing Object array.